# How the heck do I deal with Advent Stun Lancers?

Tags: xcom-2

They're super tanky, always seemingly manage to stay out of range of my squad's overwatch. The next turn, they seemingly are able to sprint across the map into range of my squad, stun one of them, then survive to the next round where they knock out another squad member into submission. If I get a successful flashbang, they default to their weapons with (somehow godly accuracy) and take down more of my men.  I've been restarting missions at least 43 times now, just because of 1 Advent Stun Lancer, and this is on Legendary, so I'd like to know, what's the best way to deal with an Advent Stun Lancer, especially on Legendary difficulty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Legend, the best way I've found to deal with them is kinda cheesy. I had two Sharpshooters at one point and a Ranger. A ranger with Phantom is a real lifesaver. Never let him get spotted and have him locate the lancer pods with the rest of your squad still in the drop zone. (This wouldn't be much help on the timed missions) You can then pick the buggers off with Squad Sight if your aim is high enough. From experience, even though the squad breaks concealment, if you're far enough away from line of sight, the aggro'ed pod has trouble finding you.

Comment: Rangers with Bladestorm will attack the stun lancer before he gets to attack them. This can kill the lancer, or stun them, preventing the attack.

Comment: @DCShannon: That is a nice side effect, but IMO nothing you can rely on tactically. Its more like a potential life saver if something went wrong already :)

Comment: @Rev1.0 I've been able to rely on it pretty consistently, but results may vary.